# Rebuild index through loop in PLSQL

Tags: indexing, plsql, for-in-loop, rebuild, ora-00942

```
FOR r IN (select 'DRR_DEV.' ||object_name as obj from dba_objects where object_type = 'INDEX' 
and owner ='DRR_DEV')
  LOOP
        l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX '||r.obj||' REBUILD'||'';
        execute immediate l_sql;
  END LOOP;
```

Above FOR..IN loop, loop all the indexes of the particular schema and rebuild. I am getting few error at the beginning of the loop and the line of ALTER statement.

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'R' use is invalid
```

I able to manually run the select statement but not through PLSQL block, what might go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you don't have a privilege to access DBA_OBJECTS. Either connect as SYS and run such a code, or grant required privileges to some other user, or  - even better - connect as DDR_DEV.

> **Ah, outside of PL/SQL it works** - sorry, didn't notice that earlier. The fact is: privileges acquired via roles won't work in
>   PL/SQL. So, if that's the case, grant SELECT ON DBA_OBJECTS directly
>   to user that runs your PL/SQL code.

I removed condition which restricts OWNER as there's no such column in USER_OBJECTS.

Here's an example ran on my SCOTT user:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test (id NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE INDEX i1
  2     ON test (id);

Index created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_sql   VARCHAR2 (100);
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR r IN (SELECT object_name AS obj
  5                 FROM user_objects
  6                WHERE object_type = 'INDEX'             -- AND owner = 'DRR_DEV'
  7                                           )
  8     LOOP
  9        l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX ' || r.obj || ' REBUILD' || '';
 10        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);
 11
 12        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
 13     END LOOP;
 14  END;
 15  /
ALTER INDEX I1 REBUILD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: so i should use DBA_OBJECTS or USER_OBJECTS? any grant required?

Comment: You don't need any additional privileges for USER_OBJECTS - it is accessible to the owner (but you have to be connected as DRR_DEV user). If you want to use DBA_OBJECTS, then you'll have to acquire direct SELECT privilege on it.

Comment: thanks, anyway if i can exclude primary index on an IOT to be rebuilt from above query?

Comment: Consider selecting values related to indexes from `USER_INDEXES` instead of `USER_OBJECTS`.

Comment: That's where I got to using select index_name from user_indexes where index_type = 'NORMAL'. Still got ORA-02243: Error.

Comment: Which means that you, probably, did something wrong. I suggest you open a new question and post code you used,  @Arthur.